# How to best code overlapping html buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, svg

Here is what I'm trying to do:

[overlapping buttons http://dev.960design.com/98a5fad8-c3ed-4014-a732-15145a233b83.png](http://dev.960design.com/98a5fad8-c3ed-4014-a732-15145a233b83.png)

I would like the red, blue and green areas to be clickable links without overlapping in an HTML5 web page.  For example, if I hover my mouse or tap on the far right edge of the Blue 'B' circle, I do not want the green to be clicked.  I would also prefer to have the 'white-space' between the links to be inactive ( hover:pointer would sort of 'blink' as you hover from red to blue to green ).

My initial thoughts: SVG buttons. No problem creating/implementing the svg buttons, but the clickable areas (viewbox?) is causing me problems.

So what is the best way of accomplishing this?

**Here's my try with SVG...**

```
<a href="#">
  <svg>
    <path id="button-svg-right" d="M0,100 L100,100 L100,0 L0,0 C27.6142375,0 50,22.3857625 50,50 C50,77.6142375 27.6142375,100 0,100 L0,100 Z"></path>
  </svg>
</a>
```

Comment: img map? (old school)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because they want their homework done

Comment: Not homework mate, real question.  Could you at least point me to how to do this?  I really would hope there is better tech out there than image maps this day and age.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a central `absolute` white `<span>` circle that is not a button.
Play with paddings, borders, till you get the desired sizes.

```css
.btns{
  position: relative;
  height: 30px;
}
.btns button{
  cursor:pointer;
  outline: none;
  border:none;
  height: inherit;
  width: 50px;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight:bold;
  font-size:24px;
}
.btns button:hover{
  opacity:0.7;
}
.btns > button:first-child{
  background: red;
  padding-right:20px;
}
.btns > button:last-child{
  background: green;
  padding-left:20px;
}
.btns span{
  left: 32px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index:1;
  width: 30px;
  height: inherit;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #fff;
  border: 5px solid #fff; margin-top:-5px;
}
.btns span button{
  width: inherit; border-radius: inherit;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<span class="btns">
  <button>-</button>
  <span>
    <button>B</button>
  </span>
  <button>+</button>  
</span>
```

Comment: Freaking brilliant!  Is it that easy?  Checking code right now, be right back for the big thank you.

Comment: @William Thx. Well, easy-not-easy, all you need to know is that the non-cursor-area is actually the inner `<span>` that wraps the central "B" button. P.S: don't get used to such answers, always try to provide the minimal code of what you tried.

Comment: `<a href="#">
  <svg>
    <path id="button-svg-right" d="M0,100 L100,100 L100,0 L0,0 C27.6142375,0 50,22.3857625 50,50 C50,77.6142375 27.6142375,100 0,100 L0,100 Z"></path>
   </svg>
</a>`

Comment: @William :D don't do that in comments, but within your Q so anyone can see and refer-to

Comment: This is a horrible!  I was trying to show the horror path I was running down with SVGs.  Cannot even write code in comments!  Sheesh!  Thank you, I see what you did and cannot believe how hard I was making this.

Comment: @William you're welcome!